# How to upgrade to the latest version of PhoneGap (cli-6.3.0)?

Tags: cordova, version, upgrade, phonegap-build, phonegap-cli

I would like to upgrade the PhoneGap version from *cli-5.2.0* to *cli-6.3.0* for my hybrid app. According to the PhoneGap [documentation](http://phonegap.com/blog/2016/08/03/cli-6_3-now-on-build/), adding the following preference in my *config.xml* file should be enough; but it's not working for me.

```
<preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-6.3.0"/>
```

When I upload my code with the updated config.xml, the build does not fail but the PhoneGap version is not updated either.

Comment: The documentation states that this is the new default, so you shouldn't need to use this on Build.

Comment: That's what I thought as well. I didn't have a phonegap-version preference in my config.xml initially; so I was expecting the latest version to be used in the build process but that wasn't the case. I solved it by a very 'complicated' method. I deleted my project from the PhoneGap console, re-created, and voilà, magic.

Comment: That's the standard method all PGB developers use! Haha. I was just going to suggest it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't been able to figure out what the actual issue is. The documentation says that cli-6.3.0 is the new default. Long story short, I deleted my project from the PhoneGap console and re-created it. It works now.

Answer (score 0):

See http://phonegap.com/blog/2013/11/28/phonegap-320-released/

**How to Upgrade PhoneGap**

Mac and Linux:

> $ sudo npm install -g phonegap

Windows:

> C:> npm install -g phonegap

**How to Upgrade an App**

> $ cd path/to/my-app
>
> $ phonegap platform update android

You can substitute android for any platform name.

Comment: This question is for PhoneGap Build not the command line version of PhoneGap.

Comment: Please read my answer again.. i first update phonegap CLI and then i upday phonegap build.

Answer (score -2):

Open up your command prompt and execute:

```
npm update -g cordova
```

or

```
npm install -g cordova@6.3.0
```

Next time first check [the documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/cli/#updating-cordova-and-your-project) of the provider.

Comment: Next time first read the title and the description more carefully. I never said I was using Apache Cordova. I'm using PhoneGap which is just a distribution of Cordova. So I don't even have Cordova installed on my computer; the build process is done in the cloud.